# Nested associations on FactoryGirl with same Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

Given the following factories:

```
factory :address do
  # some data
end

factory :apartament do
  address
end

factory :garage do
  address
end

factory :ad do
  apartament
  garage
end
```

Whenever I `create :ad` two diferent addresses are created, but I must have the same address for both  `apartament` and `garage` on the same address.

Consider that this test should pass:

```
let(:ad) { create :ad }
it { expect(ad.apartament.address.id).to eq ad.garage.address.id }
```

Some notes:

1. It must be default, always using the same address for associations (not a `trait`)
2. It must allow override `:apartament` or `:garage` (`create :ad, garage: my_garage`)

Answer (score 0):

Remember these are factories, not fixtures. With the way you have the factories, you will need to create more than just the `:ad`. Otherwise, every call to `:address` is like a new db record.

I believe this would work:

```
  let(:address)    { create :address }
  let(:apartament) { create :apartament, address: address }
  let(:garage)     { create :garage, address: address }
  let(:ad)         { create :ad, garage: garage, apartament: apartament }
  it { expect(ad.apartament.address.id).to eq ad.garage.address.id }
```

To be able to call only `:ad`, perhaps try `FactoryGirl.create()`:

```
  factory :address do
    # some data
  end

  factory :apartament do
    address
  end

  factory :garage do
    address
  end

  factory :ad do
    address = FactoryGirl.create(:address)
    apartament FactoryGirl.create(:apartament, address: address)
    garage FactoryGirl.create(:garage, address: address)
  end
```

Comment: The whole point of this question is to avoid explicity creation of `:address`, `:apartament` and `:garage` every time I need an `:ad`.

Comment: Ah I see. When you said 'given the following factories' I thought you meant you wanted to keep the factories as they are shown. I will edit my answer to show how you can avoid creation of the other entities.